# Create an org-agenda-custom-commands using org-agenda-filter

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use the org-agenda-filter pretty heavily as part of my daily agenda workflow. I have a tag for "Work" related TODO items and repeat this operation several times a day:

Pressing C-a a
invoke the org-agenda-filter using /
filter to my tag and TODO items of interest e.g. Work/TODO

I want to create a custom filter command for this.

So far, I have worked on this:

`(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(("w" "List Work Tasks" ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-span 'week))) (org-agenda-filter '("Work/TODO"))))))`

However, when I press C-a w, it asks me to enter my Tag/TODO keywords again. It seems like this code is not able to pass the search terms to org-agenda filter.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to use `org-agenda-filter-apply`, for example `(org-agenda-filter-apply '("+MYTAG") 'tag)` to show only MYTAG and `(org-agenda-filter-show-all-tag)` to clear the filter.
This is just a starting point. Take a look at the source for `org-agenda-filter-by-tag` to get more information.